# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' - Error when saving users in ajax call

Tags: django, ajax

**Views.py**
The following attempt to save both my student (which extends User model) and my user, gives a long series of errors. What is the best way around this?  I assume this is happening because it's an ajax call.  I have been able to user the .save() in other views without an issue.  Django version is 2.1.15

```
@login_required
def start_membership(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            ...
            student.membership_start = membership_start_dt
            student.membership_end = membership_end_dt
            student.save()

            user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            user.membership = True
            user.save()
            ...
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[21/Jul/2020 00:09:40] "POST /students/start_membership/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

---

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60090)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\socketserver.py", line 803, in write
self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\ssenv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\ssenv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\ssenv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
self.close()
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\ssenv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
super().close()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly a permanent answer, but I did find a way to resolve the aborted connection by setting the ajax request in jquery to async: false
even though this is deprecated, the ajax call runs smoothly without throwing an error.